# Comma separated string to Map - Mulesoft

Tags: java, string, csv, dictionary, mule

I have a comma separated string which look like this

```
    CODE,TYPE,BATCHDATE
    SQ22,LOAD,20170505
    SF55,LPOO,20170908
    PL25,KLLQ,20170707
```

I want to create a payload map which look like this

```
    CODE=SQ22,TYPE=LOAD,BATCHDATE=20170505
    CODE=SF55,TYPE=LPOO,BATCHDATE=20170908
    CODE=PL25,TYPE=KLLQ,BATCHDATE=20170707
```

What is the best approach to do so? I've tried a transformer between the string and other transformer but iam always getting exceptions.[Example of flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaeVk.png)

```
    %dw 1.0
    $output application/csv
    ---
    payload
```

and the second transformer is

```
    %dw 1.0
    $output application/java
    ---
    payload map ((payload,index) -> {
    batchCode: payload.CODE,
    batchType: payload.TYPE,
    batchDate: payload.BATCHDATE
    } as :object {
    class: "com.example.integration.Batch"
    })
```

Any ideas where i am making mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine for both cases. Please try to change dataweave directive from `$output application/java` to `%output application/java`.

Update:-
As per error mentioned dataweave is expecting xml input. Please add mime type for CSV `<dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv"/>`. Code will look like

```
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv"/>
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
            %output application/java
            ---
            payload]]>
        </dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still the same result , exception is : Unexpected character 'C (code 85) in prolog; expected '<'